# Approximately how long will it take for sunchoke to appear after planting?

Tags: planting, sprouting

Approximately how long does it take for sunchoke to go from planting to sprouting above the ground?

Comment: I have always planted in the fall, and they popped in the spring.  I would imagine 4 weeks or so to pop in the spring but it's just a guess.

Comment: Will it run out of food by the time it reaches the top if you accidentally buried it too deep?

Comment: Possible but if it's 6-8 inches down should be fine.  More than a foot may be a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on when it is planted. I planted mine in mid December ( early summer for me ) and it came up 2-3 weeks later which is what one expects.  It's now 8 foot tall in mid autumn.